# How to join 3 and more tables in SQL where two of them need to join

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

Costs:

- items,
- amount;

Production:

- Model,
- Volume;

Hours:

- Model,
- Hours;

i need to create a query
where
I will have 3 columns

- items from Costs
- amount from Costs
- cost per hour = Costs.Amount/Sum(Production.Volume*Hours.Hours) as CPH

I tried this query which does not work

```
SELECT Costs.items, Costs.amount,    
(sum([Costs].Amount)/SUM(Round([Hours].Hours*[Production].Volume,1))) as CPH
FROM Costs
(From Hours Inner join Production on Production.Model = Hours.Model);
```

Could you please help?

Comment: There should be a relation between Costs and Production or Hours to make a correct calculation. I see only relation between Production and Hours via Model